# Do 6-month old babies ingest more aluminum from formula milk than from vaccines?

Tags: medical-science, vaccines, milk, aluminum

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180810194402/http://www.preemieprimer.com/the-truth-about-vaccines-and-toxins-less-aluminum-than-breast-milk/) claims that vaccines given to infants contain less aluminum than is typically ingested from milk - especially formula milk. A more prestigious source of this claim is the [Children's Hospital of Philadelphia](https://www.chop.edu/centers-programs/vaccine-education-center/vaccine-ingredients/aluminum#.VdJoZixViko). They state:

> While infants receive about 4.4 milligrams of aluminum in the first six months of life from vaccines, they receive more than that in their diet. Breast-fed infants ingest about 7 milligrams, formula-fed infants ingest about 38 milligrams, and infants who are fed soy formula ingest almost 117 milligrams of aluminum during the first six months of life.

However, [this paper in Pediatric Nephrology](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00869743) says that the average infant on formula *absorbs* .0008 mg Al per kg of body weight per day ([the breast-fed infant receives significantly less - on the order of 1/10](https://journals.lww.com/jpgn/Fulltext/1999/03000/Aluminum_Contents_of_Human_Milk,_Cow_s_Milk,_and.11.aspx?WT.mc_id=HPxADx20100319xMP)). I can't resolve how this matches the claims above.

Is it true that more aluminum is ingested in the first six months of formula-drinking infant than is injected or ingested by the scheduled vaccines?

Comment: Whatever the calculations about the amount of aluminium (aluminum for US readers), you also have to take into account the chemistry of the compounds: some are essentially completely inert and will simply pass through the body (eg the hydroxide in antacids).

Comment: @mmr added citation with comparison of Al in breast milk/formula. I think the forms of Al question is basically the crux here - most of the Al in breast milk (or Al taken orally in general) will not enter the blood stream.

Comment: I think you may be confusing milligrams with micrograms in some of the papers.  Also, basic chemistry seems to be a matter of confusion.  Just think of the difference between Methyl and Ethyl alcohol...

Comment: @LarianLeQuella anything specific or just a feeling? :D

Comment: http://www.nature.com/jes/journal/v20/n7/abs/jes200964a.html

Comment: I also reduced the commentary to just the claim and my basic calculations that seem to refute it.

Comment: I removed the calculations. They contained a lot of assumptions about baby weights, confused ingested with absorbed, and generally distracted from the question - it isn't an answer to point out errors in your calculations. Re-opened.

Comment: Side note: Injected, ingested and absorbed are different concepts. The basic idea of comparing the weight of Aluminum ingested versus injected seems a non-sequitur. I'll happily ingest a lot more beer than I will inject.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that the CHoP claim is technically true but is an intentional deception based on the pharmacokinetics of intramuscular versus oral aluminum.

Comment: I suspect they get the most from the tin hats of their parents.

Comment: FWIW, if that 0.0008 mg/kg/day number is accurate, it suggests babies would absorb ~0.75mg in that 6-month period.

Comment: Nobody ingests aluminum from vaccines.

Comment: From a paper CHOP cites, [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264410X02001652): "The calculated body burden of aluminum **from vaccinations exceeds that from dietary sources**, however, it is below the minimal risk level equivalent curve after the brief period following injection." Does this seem contrary to CHOP statements?

Comment: Also, I didn't see the numbers in any of CHOP's citations.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland "most of the Al in breast milk ...will not enter the blood stream" I am not sure how this could be true, everything in breastmilk gets there via the bloodstream of the mother.

Comment: @fredsbend Why do you say nobody ingests aluminum from vaccines?  There are oral vaccines.

Comment: @LorenPechtel There's few, and none in the regular child schedule. Further, none I know of with aluminum.

Comment: @fredsbend None in the child schedule doesn't mean nobody.  And while aluminum probably isn't an actual component that doesn't mean there isn't a trace amount anyway.